# Async ajax upload firefox doesn't work

Tags: ajax, firefox

My ajax async works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. How to adapt it in Firefox ?

```
html2canvas($('#col2Game'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "upload.php?id="+idPicture,
            data: { 'base64data' : canvas.toDataURL() },
        });
    }
});
```

This is to upload pictures.

This is the error when I get the ajax call :

[image]

Comment: Please read [this]http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/02/jquery-async-ajax-interrupts-ie-not.html

Comment: it still not resolve the problem ..

Comment: Do you get an error in the console when firing the ajax-call?

Comment: I put the picture of my error in my OP, i just updated it.

Comment: sorry its french ...